# wordpress json encode issue 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach'

Tags: php, ajax, json, wordpress

```
 $data = $_POST['data'];
 $result=json_encode($data, true);
 foreach($result as $value)
  {
    echo $value['Country'];
  }
```

Here i'm trying to get the **Country** value but is says **Invalid argument supplied for foreach**

Also this should loop..any idea how to make this work?

Thank you!.

Comment: try var_dump($result); and show what you are getting?

Comment: the encoded string is not iterable, maybe you meant `decode`, very vague, if `$data` is already an array, just ditch the encoding part.

Comment: i think you need json_decode(@data,true);

Comment: this is what i'm sending @Priyank    `[{"Country Code":"bob","Country":"503","Description":"bobby","\"Minute Rate":"oregon","USD\"":"","\"$5 Talk Time":"\r"},{"Country Code":"steve","Country":"707","Description":"stevie","\"Minute Rate":"california","USD\"":"","\"$5 Talk Time":"\r"},{"Country Code":"dsfd","Country":"342","Description":"dfdfs","\"Minute Rate":"dfdsfs","USD\"":"","\"$5 Talk Time":"\r"},{"Country Code":"sada","Country":"342","Description":"sdsad","\"Minute Rate":"dfsffd","USD\"":"","\"$5 Talk Time":"\r"},{"Country Code":""}]`

Comment: Can you tell me that what html you are using to get value from $_POST['data'];

Comment: please show print_r( $data )?

Comment: @gaurav [{\"Country Code\":\"bob\",\"Country\":\"503\",\"Description\":\"bobby\",\"\\\"Minute Rate\":\"oregon\",\"USD\\\"\":\"\",\"\\\"$5 Talk Time\":\"\\r\"},{\"Country Code\":\"steve\",\"Country\":\"707\",\"Description\":\"stevie\",\"\\\"Minute Rate\":\"california\",\"USD\\\"\":\"\",\"\\\"$5 Talk Time\":\"\\r\"},{\"Country Code\":\"\"}]`

Comment: $res = json_decode( $data , true); print_r( $res ); then show output?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
$result=json_decode($data, true);
foreach($result as $value)
{
echo $value['Country'];
}
```

Comment: @jehan try like this :)

Comment: I tried @Priyank it says "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" wordpress

Comment: @jehan ok do like this :$result=json_decode($data, true); var_dump($result); and show me what is the result

Comment: it says "null" @Priyank

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
$result=json_decode($data);
foreach ((array) $result->data as $key=>$value))
{
echo $value['Country'];
}
```

Comment: See my updated answer, and let me know what error you are getting now or do you see any result?